# Spam Request coming from google ip: "Mediapartners-Google" "72.14.199.26" : It makes my website down

Tags: nginx, server, spam, google-search-console, ddos

I am getting thousands of spam request coming from Mediapartners-Google crowler and these pages are not exists and requests are dublicate. and almost came twice a second.

This effects my website and it's down due to heavy load. and I need to restart the server. Server setup Ubuntu, nginx, apache, php.

72.14.199.26 - - [05/Apr/2018:00:45:05 +0000] "GET /4%20differences%20between%20bank%20loan%20and%20overdraft HTTP/1.1" 404 534 "-" "Mediapartners-Google" "72.14.199.26" 362 0.003 "891" "0.000" ""
72.14.199.26 - - [05/Apr/2018:00:45:10 +0000] "GET /accident%20lawyers%20san%20antonio HTTP/1.1" 404 534 "-" "Mediapartners-Google" "72.14.199.26" 339 0.005 "891" "0.004" ""
72.14.199.26 - - [05/Apr/2018:00:45:10 +0000] "GET /bank%20loan%20marketing%20ideas HTTP/1.1" 404 534 "-" "Mediapartners-Google" "72.14.199.26" 336 0.002 "891" "0.000" ""
72.14.199.26 - - [05/Apr/2018:00:45:14 +0000] "GET /bank%20loan%2010%20down HTTP/1.1" 404 534 "-" "Mediapartners-Google" "72.14.199.26" 328 0.003 "891" "0.000" ""
72.14.199.26 - - [05/Apr/2018:00:45:16 +0000] "GET /buy%20domains%20with%20bitcoin HTTP/1.1" 404 534 "-" "Mediapartners-Google" "72.14.199.26" 335 0.002 "891" "0.000" ""
72.14.199.26 - - [05/Apr/2018:00:45:16 +0000] "GET /bank%20loan%20securities HTTP/1.1" 404 534 "-" "Mediapartners-Google" "72.14.199.26" 329 0.002 "891" "0.000" ""

What do you think, what should I do?

Thanks,
James

Comment: I blocked these IPs from Cloudflare, dont know who is sending these, I dont think this could be google.

Answer (score 0):

Add Mediapartners-Google to Robots.txt and disallow it

in robots.txt add these two lines

```
User-agent: Mediapartners-Google
Disallow: /
```

Comment: this solution is not working and why google domain is spamming?